# jQuery - select document that called ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 files : parent.html and child.html

parent.html calls child.html with jquery ajax $.get / $.post

now, in child.html, I want to access parent.html (not using iframe)

Commands like

```
$("#id", window.parent.document).doSomething();
```

doesn't work. How can this be achieved?

Comment: "in child.html, I want to access parent.html" >> Be more specific here

Comment: i believe there is an architecture issue here more than a use case as you have posted.  Please post example code in jsfiddle and that will allow real help.

Comment: if you are not using iframe/window then you can just say `$('#id')`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when you are trying to access $("#parent_id").

If you are calling $("#parent_id") in some script tag in "child.html" directly, it won't work because you won't have the html loaded yet.

If it is a result of an event call after you've loaded the child, it should work.

For example, this should work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var child_html = "<button onclick=\"$('#update_me').html('hello!')\">click me!</button>";
        $("#place_for_child").append(child_html);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="update_me"></div>
<div id="place_for_child"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The variable `child_html` can be loaded from a separate file.

Here's the [jsfiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdQN3/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.opener,If you are using child as parent window

```
         window.opener.$("#id").doSomething();
```

If you are loading child.html inside parent.html,Then you can simply use

```
            $("#id").doSomething();
```

Because ,Child.html loaded inside parent.html,It is also a part of parent.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `$.load`/`$.get` to load the contents of the `child.html` to an existing element in `parent.html` then `$('#id')` will be enough

Comment: can you share how the element is loaded when the selector is uused?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making an ajax request from parent.html you will receive back the html markup of child.html.  This is very different from opening a child window which can then interact with its parent window.

Your javascript on child.html won't be run in this case because it is never loaded into a browser window. If you want the code to execute you will have to do it manually with Eval.

It sounds like you need to rethink how your pages interact. The normal used case for ajax is to pull in data asynchronously. if you want to pull in functionality look at a library like require.js